# Object is not set in ViewModel class and control is directly move from data access class to View

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I want to fetch first record from AboutUs table and display as a content label.

I have created 4 classes in MVVM pattern.

**First is Model class AboutUs.cs**

> ```
> [Table("tblAboutUs")]
>     public class AboutUs
>     {
>         [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
>         public int IDP { get; set; }
>         public string Content { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

**Second is Data Access class**

SQLiteAboutUs.cs

> ```
> public class SQLiteAboutUs
>     {
>         private static readonly AsyncLock Mutex = new AsyncLock();
>         private SQLiteAsyncConnection dbConn;
>
>         public int StatusCode { get; set; }
>
>         public SQLiteAboutUs(ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, string dbPath)
>         {
>
>             if (dbConn == null)
>             {
>                 var connectionFunc = new Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock>(() =>
>                     new SQLiteConnectionWithLock
>                     (
>                         sqlitePlatform,
>                         new SQLiteConnectionString(dbPath, storeDateTimeAsTicks: false)
>                     ));
>
>                 dbConn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(connectionFunc);
>                 dbConn.CreateTableAsync<Model.AboutUs>();
>             }
>         }
>
>         public SQLiteAboutUs()
>         {
>         }
>         public async Task Save(Model.AboutUs content)
>         {
>             using (await Mutex.LockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
>             {
>                 StatusCode = 0;
>
>
>             await dbConn.InsertAsync(new Model.AboutUs { Content = content.Content });
>             StatusCode = 1;
>         }
>
>         //For Get first Row from Table
>         public async Task<Model.AboutUs> GetAllData()
>         {
>             return await dbConn.Table<Model.AboutUs>().Where(x => x.IDP == 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
>         }
>     }
> ```

**Third class ViewModel Class**

AboutUsViewModel.cs

> ```
> public class AboutUsViewModel
>     {
>         readonly SQLiteAboutUs _db;
>         public string AboutUsContent { get; set; }
>
>         //public string AboutUs;  
>         public AboutUsViewModel()
>         {
>             _db = new SQLiteAboutUs();
>         }
>         public async void FirstRecord()
>         {
>             Model.AboutUs obj = await _db.GetAllData();
>             this.AboutUsContent = obj.Content;
>         }
>     }
> ```

**Forth one is Code behind file of my xaml pages.**

AboutUs.xaml.cs

> ```
> public partial class AboutUs : ContentPage
>     {
>         readonly AboutUsViewModel aboutUsViewModel;
>         public AboutUs()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>
>             aboutUsViewModel = new AboutUsViewModel();
>
>             aboutUsViewModel.FirstRecord();
>
>             lblContent.Text = aboutUsViewModel.AboutUsContent;
>         }
>     }
> ```

I have debug code but problem is In AboutUsViewModel.cs class in FirstRecord Method object can not be set that's why AboutUsContent string property is also not set.

**I can't figure out why my debugger directly jump from GetAllData() method in SQLiteAboutUs.cs to label.text in code behind file of view?**

Comment: What is exactly being null here? Are you sure dbConn is not null? It happened to me many times. can you also try to assign a variable like this? var result= await dbConn.Table<Model.AboutUs>().Where(x => x.IDP == 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

with a try catch maybe, just to make sure if FirstOrDefaultAsync makes the problem or return type makes the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome in the wonderfull world of asynchronicity. I encourage you to read carefully about how await is working: [How and When to use `async` and `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

It is not a blocking call. Thus you create the view AboutUs. It creates the ViewModel AboutUsViewModel. It calls

```
aboutUsViewModel.FirstRecord();
```

But does not wait for the call to be complete (dont't forget you marked your FirstRecord function as async...)

So it calls

```
Model.AboutUs obj = await _db.GetAllData();
```

And directly return to the caller because of the await operator.
That's why it directly jump to

```
lblContent.Text = aboutUsViewModel.AboutUsContent;
```

What you would like is Something like

```
await aboutUsViewModel.FirstRecord();
```

To wait the call to be complete before going to the next line. But of course you can't do that, because you are in a constructor and you can't have an async constructor. And calling a database (or actually anything that could likely failed) in a constructor is a bad practice anyway.

I would advise you to let only InitializeComponent() in the constructor, and then use Something like the OnDataLoaded() event of your view to perform your async call with a await.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for encourage me. Not I see the actual problem. I can't find OnDataLoaded() method in xamarin.forms. So I am using OnAppearing() method.

Comment: but problem is when GetAllData Method call it gives me error "Object reference not set to the instance of the object".

Comment: OnAppearing is probably to soon, you should look for another event later, or just call something like a initialize function by hand.